# Error On Launching Default Audio Player By Intent From Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have an application in which i will need to play an mp3 file
located on the phone sdcard.

The application uses fragments,from which i am trying to launch the default AudioPlayer using an intent

```
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaStorageDir + "/" + name);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
```

The above code causes the following error:

```
       No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/EFiles/1.mp3 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:829)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:897)
```

I guess there is an issue arising because this action is performed from a fragment and not an activity.

However, how can i lauch the default audio player using an intent from within 
a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Activity try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
```

but be careful because it's deprecated, now you have to use(read the NOTE in the API doc)

> public static final String CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC Added in API level 15
>
> Used with ACTION_MAIN to launch the music application. The activity
>   should be able to play, browse, or manipulate music files stored on
>   the device.
>
> NOTE: This should not be used as the primary key of an Intent, since
>   it will not result in the app launching with the correct action and
>   category. Instead, use this with makeMainSelectorActivity(String,
>   String) to generate a main Intent with this category in the selector.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC"

For a Fragment, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Edited, try now with intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Intent.ACTION_VIEW by this.getActivity()

Comment: This does not work.It gives an error stating the getActivity() method can not be resolved.

Comment: if you remove this? and just put getActivity() ?

Comment: Or try this as well getActivity().startActivity(myIntent)